Transmission Remote List magnets/URLs
I use transmission remote terminal command and I want to re-create the current state of my torrent files in other computer using a bash script.
I want to create a bash script that will list all the magnet links/URLs of my current state transmission-remote. This to be capable to save those links easily and recreate the state of my torrents in another machine if needed.
Commands like transmission-remote -l only list the names and metadata of the torrents but that is not enough to re-created the state that I have now. Plus will forced me to save those links manually in some text file each time I add a new one to transmission.
Any Ideas? There is a command in transmission-remote who gave the magnet links/URLs information.

Total off topic but I will tell you what you are trying to do is not going to work. Find the data files of the install and copy the entire contents to the other computer. When you start Transmission on the other computer it will read the data file and you have cloned and or removed the apps data.

Ok, I was hoping there was a command that will listed them so I can download them via torrent in other machines. Thanks

I find the answer, it turns up that all the .torrent files will be saved in ~/.config/transmission-daemon/torrents, at least in my machine. So I can take them from there

Which is what I told you.
